# Python one liner conditional

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can anyone please explain what this code is for?

```
shift, range = order < self.order and (1, (to, orig-1)) or (-1, (orig+1, to))
```

I know it will set shift and range depending on the result of `order < self.order`

What I don't know is why there is an `and` and `or` statement there

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/394887/5031339

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @Cyphase: which is why I linked directly to a relevant answer. That question also gives quite a bit more context to why someone would write a statement like that.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen, whoops, I didn't see that you posted both of those, and I didn't notice that the first was directly to an answer :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation of boolean expressions in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) -

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x` ; if `x` is false, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> The expression `x or y` first evaluates x; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

So `and` / `or` expressions in Python don't necessarily return `True` or `False`, instead -

1. For `and` it return the last evaluated `False` value, or if all values are `True` , they return the last evaluated value.
2. For `or` it returns the last evaluated `True` value, or if all values are `False`, it returns the last evaluated value.

So , in your case if the condition is true , it returns the value of `(1, (to, orig-1))`  , otherwise it returns the value of `(-1, (orig+1, to))` .

Very simple examples to show this -

```
>>> 1 < 5 and 2 or 4
2
>>> 6 < 5 and 2 or 4
4
```

---

Also, though not directly applicable to the condition , but in a general case, for a condition like -

```
cond and a or b
```

if `cond` is a True-like value and `a` has a False-like value (like `0` or empty string/list/tuple, etc), it would return `b` . Example -

```
>>> 1 < 5 and 0 or 2
2
```

So, it would be better to use the equivalent `if..else` ternary expression, Example -

```
a if cond else b
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a logical error in this code - when `order < self.order` evaluates to `True`, an exception will be raised.

I believe this is what is intended:

```
shift, range = (1, (to, orig - 1)) if order < self.order else (-1, (orig + 1, to))
```

This will assign 1 to shift and `(to, orig - 1)` to range when `order < self.order` is True and -1 to shift and `(orig + 1, to)` to range when `order >= self.order`